# What is a more efficient way to check for duplicates in an array of sets

Tags: javascript, arrays, duplicates, set, space-complexity

given this input:

```
const set1 = new Set([10, "someText", {a: 1, b: 2}]);
const set2 = new Set([10, "someText", {a: 1, b: 2}]);
const set3 = new Set([5, "someText", {a: 3, b: 4}]);
const arr = [set1, set2, set3];

combineDupSets(arr);
```

Wanted result:

```
[
  Set { 10, 'someText', { a: 1, b: 2 } },
  Set { 5, 'someText', { a: 3, b: 4 } }
]
```

I am writing a function to eliminate all the duplicate sets, and since Set() won't check for duplicates when it's an object or set itself, I wrote the following:

```
function combineDupSets(arr) {
  const hold = [];

  arr.forEach(set =>{
    const copySet = [...set];
    const stringify = JSON.stringify(copySet);
    if(hold.indexOf(stringify) === -1) {
      hold.push(stringify)
    }
  })


  const end = hold.map(item => JSON.parse(item));

  const res = end.map(item => item = new Set(item))

  return res;
}
```

Here, I have to use 3 arrays sized O(n) to check for this, and I was just wondering if there's any other solution that is readable that will be more efficient in checking for this for both time and space complexity?

Thank you

Comment: When are two Sets equal? If they contain the same elements? Does insertion order matter?

Comment: please add the wanted result.

Comment: I would like to understand why you want this data structure.

Comment: Wanted result added! Insertion order doesn't matter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `indexOf` in an array, consider putting the sets onto an object or Map, where the key is the stringified set and the value is the original set. Assuming that the values are in order:

```
function combineDupSets(arr) {
   const uniques = new Map();
   for (const set of arr) {
      uniques.set(JSON.stringify([...set]), set);
   }
   return [...uniques.values()];
}
```

This

- iterates over the `arr` (`O(n)`)
- iterates over each item inside once (total of `O(n * m)` - there's no getting around that)
- Iterates over the created Map and puts it into an array (`O(n)`)

If the set values aren't necessarily in order - eg, if you have

```
Set([true, 'foo'])
Set(['foo', true])
```

that should be considered equal, then it'll get a lot more complicated, since every item in each Set not only has to be iterated over, but also compared against *every other item in every other Set* somehow. One way to implement this is to sort by the stringified values:

```
function combineDupSets(arr) {
   const uniques = new Map();
   for (const set of arr) {
      const key = [...set].map(JSON.stringify).sort().join();
      uniques.set(key, set);
   }
   return [...uniques.values()];
}
```

Comment: Nice once! Can you return `unique.values()` or do you have to use the spread operator?

Comment: `.values` returns an *iterator*, so if you want an array as the result, you'll have to spread the iterator into an array.

Comment: Got it. So another question: If I use indexOf, the time complexity will be O(n), but if I use a map, since I added O(n*m) time, why is that more efficient? Or is it more efficient because we only create another array and a map instead of 3 arrays, but would they be simplified to O(n)?

Comment: The `JSON.stringify(copySet)` - or the `JSON.stringify([...set])` - is `O(m)` where `m` is the number of items in the set. But then your approach of `hold.indexOf(stringify)` is *another* `O(n)`, where `n` is the number of sets. In contrast, the Map approach of `uniques.set` is an `O(1)` operation.

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate the sets and check the values and treat object only equal if they share the same object reference.

```js
function combineDupSets(array) {
    return array.reduce((r, s) => {
        const values = [...s];
        if (!r.some(t => s.size === t.size && values.every(Set.prototype.has, t))) r.push(s);
        return r;
    }, []);
}

const
    a = { a: 1, b: 2 },
    b = { a: 3, b: 4 },
    set1 = new Set([10, "someText", a]),
    set2 = new Set([10, "someText", a]),
    set3 = new Set([5, "someText", b]),
    arr = [set1, set2, set3];

console.log(combineDupSets(arr).map(s => [...s]));
```